# What's the best API call to retrieve the Id of a DialogFlow Intent if you just know the Display Name?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using DialogFlow ES and the PHP Client Library. I can create intents with no issue, using code like this:

```
$intent = (new Intent())
            ->setDisplayName($displayName)
            ->setTrainingPhrases($trainingPhrases)
            ->setMessages([$message]);
            $response = $intentsClient->createIntent($parent, $intent);
```

But when creating an Intent and an exception is thrown because an Intent with that name already exists I get this error message: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Intent with the display name ‘example display name’ already exists and a code 3.

That's ok as all I then want to do is to either delete the Intent and re-create it or update it. But I need the Intent Id to do an update or delete.

Nowhere in the exception after the create can I find the Id of the Intent that already exists, or it just may not be there!

getIntent needs the Intent string with its Id so I can’t use that.

I could loop through all the Intents in the Agent (up to 2000 of them), but don't think that's the most elegant way. Is there another way to get the Id if I just know the Display Name?

Cheers, Vic

Comment: I also posted this question to Google DialogFlow support and they confirmed with me that currently there is no API call to lookup the Id just passing the Display Name. They suggested to use listIntents. http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.149.0/dialogflow/v2/intentsclient?method=listIntents